# Angular - Moving function into a service

Tags: angularjs

I have a function that I'm now needing to use in multiple page so decided to move into a service - however its not going as I'm expecting.

So in my HTML i have:

```
<li ng-init="bg = underQBar(work.options)">
```

Then in the controller (before I moved the common function) it looked like:

```
$scope.underQBar = function(toWorkArray) {
  //some implementation, with a return at the end
}
```

Now I've made my service:

```
function barService($window){
      var self = this;

      self.getBarColours = function(toWorkArray) {
         //copied the implementation with the return here
      }
}
```

And therefore trying this in my controller:

```
$scope.underQBar = barService.getBarColours(toWorkArray);
```

However this doesnt work, its not getting the parameter I'm sending from the HTML - is this a trivial fix or something wrong with the implementation?

Comment: Could you try this? `$scope.underQBar = function (toWorkArray) { return barService.getBarColours(toWorkArray) };`

Comment: Great this works! Is this the cleanest way to implement though? or can i improve?

Comment: I think you can do `$scope.underQBar = barService.getBarColours;`. The problem with your original code was that you were assigning the *result* of `getBarColours(toWorkArray` to `$scope.underQBar`, not the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
$scope.underQBar = barService.getBarColours(toWorkArray);
```

Here, you're assigning the *result* of the service function call to `$scope.underQBar`, when you meant to assign it the function itself.

This should work:

```
$scope.underQBar = barService.getBarColours;
```

If you want to make it more clear to the reader that it's a function, just do:

```
$scope.underQBar = function (toWorkArray) {
  return barService.getBarColours(toWorkArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correct definition for your service :

```
angular.module("myModule").factory("BarService", ["$window", function($window){
    var service = {};

    service.getBarColours = function(toWorkArray){
         //copied the implementation with the return here
    };

    return service;
}]);
```

And here is a correct way to inject the service in your controller :

```
angular.module("myModule").controller("controllerName", ["BarService", function(BarService){
    var self = this;

    self.getBarColours = BarService.getBarColours;
}]);
```

and here is the way to use it:

```
<li ng-init="bg = controllerName.underQBar(work.options)">
```

Explanation :

A service or a factory in angular cannot be accessed by your view. Your view can only make a call to your controllers.
If your function should have been called by many controllers, you can put this function in a global controller that will be responsible for controlling your whole view.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with their service definition, they're just using `.service` instead of `.factory`

Comment: If you use `.factory`, you need to return the service object. If you use `.service` the `this` object will be returned by default.

Comment: I found teh reply in the original question comment worked.

Comment: @georgeawg thx for pointing me I forgot to add the return. But where do you see his service/factory declaration?